# Email an image via custom url scheme

Tags: email, url

I am using custom url schemes. I can send string messages as parameters to my custom url and emailing this to any person. When any person opens this email attachment in device in it open my app installed in device with the passed parameters in my custom url.

Similarly how to email an image via custom url and when any person opens this attachment the image is passed to my app in device.

I tried to encode the image in base64 format and tried to append to my url,but not working.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Scheme tag is reserved for the programming language scheme.

Comment: no its not show me where it says that

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: HOW YOU DOIN

Comment: The fact the it's utterly useless in this context?  'Scheme' means the programming language, while 'url-scheme' or similar would fit here.

Answer (score 0):

While there technically isn't a limit placed on url length by the standards, in practice, there is (see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length) questions here on SO).

My guess is that you're running into that limit.