# Display URL variables in webpage using PHP

Tags: php, forms, url, variables

I have data being passed via HTTP post to another page. Essentially passing data from one server to another. On the target page, I cannot get the URL variable to be seen by php. Am I doning something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

URL string:

> form_listener.php?
>   contactId=101460&inf_custom_ddState=IN&inf_custom_txtZipCode=46268&inf_custom_ddClientDegreeId=729&inf_custom_txtCity=indianapolis&inf_custom_txtLastName=Anderson&inf_form_xid=f28acf3ff321cb273cb4696e996008e0&inf_custom_ddStartSemesterYear=Fall2012&inf_custom_ddMilitaryAffiliation=Yes&infusionsoft_version=1.23.11.30&inf_custom_txtFirstName=someone&inf_custom_txtAddress2=&inf_custom_txtAddress1=4707+East+72nd+Street&inf_custom_ddHSGradYearCustomLiberty=2011&inf_form_name=LibertyOnline&inf_option_Signmeupforthenewsletter=432&inf_custom_txtEmailAddress=killing.fields%40gmail.com&inf_custom_affiliateid=D80576&inf_custom_ddEducationLevel=CLGJ&captcha.typed=jydqb

PHP Code:

```
$ddState= $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];

echo $_GET['ddState'];

?>
```

Comment: your url is 684 characters long. You might have issues as it contains more than 255 car. <EDIT> No, seems like I was wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url

Comment: I think that last line should be `echo $ddState`?

Comment: @JMax standards don't put any limit on URL length, but some browsers put an artificial limit.  IE is the lowest that I know, with only 4096 chars.

Comment: @tandu Servers can limit it as well; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1289585/212218

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `ddState` in the URI. You want: `echo $ddState;` (because that is the variable where you copied the data to) or rather (to avoid opening up an XSS security hole) you actually want:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($ddState);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ddState= $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];

echo $ddState;
// or 
echo $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$_GET` you are telling php that the variable is from the URL.
By doing this:

`$ddState = $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];`

you are "creating" a local variable (`$ddState`) with the content of `$_GET['inf_custom_ddState']`, so you don't have to use `$_GET` variable anymore.

So your echo can be in 2 ways:

1. `echo $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];`
2. `echo $ddState;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use either this way

```
echo $_GET['inf_custom_ddState'];
```

Or

```
$ddstate=$_GET['inf_custom_ddState']; 
echo $ddstate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo should just be `echo $ddState;`

You are assigning the value of the URL variable to a local variable.  Once that's done, you are dealing with something that is locally scoped.

Answer (score 0):

As the `$_GET` and `$_POST` are global array, you can use the following code to see the values:

```
echo "<pre>Get data</pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "<pre>Post data</pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

Check whether these variables are set in the request. If not, try to use the post method, as it can hold more data than get method.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, make sure that your page is getting request parameters. Try `$_REQUEST['inf_custom_ddState']` or print all variables using `print_r($_REQUEST)`.

`$_REQUEST` is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. If anyting is passing to page then it should get printed.