# How many urls can be queried using Facebook's FQL api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Looking to do a query like:

```
select url,like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count from link_stat where url in("http://bing.com", "http://google.com", "http://facebook.com", "http://twitter.com")
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation that limits the number of urls that can be queried at any one time.

Comment: [here][1] States Allowed size of URI is 8177 characters in GET request

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length