# Updating Blob data using iOS and android - variation

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios

I was working on a project where I had to upload an image file as BLOB data to a MySQL database from an iOS app and an android app. I used the following code

## for iOS:

```
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 0.9);
```

and the following code was inserting the image data:

```
NSString *encodedString = [[imageData base64Encoding] urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString  *insertURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:IP]stringByAppendingString: @":8888/MasterTableInsert.php?id=%@&pf=%@&coord=%@&ct=%@"],[processID urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],encodedString ,[locationCoor urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[currentTimeInString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The php scripts is the same as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/6d9GvaWe)

## for android

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                String image_str = new String(Base64.encode(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT));
                System.out.println(camTime + "picture taken time");
                System.out.println(image_str + "image encoded string");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",encodedPid));
                 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coord",loc));
                 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ct",camTime));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pf", image_str));
                
                
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(constants.URL + "MasterTableInsertJava.php" );

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF_8"));


                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

and the PHP code is same as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/bikMiqqu)

The problem i see is, with iOS any BLOB content of more than 5kib is not inserted into the table, however with android it works fine even if the BLOB content size is around 20kib and plus. Any idea why would this happen? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Please evaluate my answer and accept it or explain why it didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between both cases is that you are sending the image as a `GET` parameter from iOS and as `POST` in the case of Android. So the most probably cause is a URI length limit set on your server. You have two possible solutions:

1. Change your iOS code to use `POST` (recommended), as described in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request) or in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH8-SW3).
2. Increase the URI length limit on your server. If you are using Apache, you need to change or add a [`LimitRequestLine` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline). The default for Apache is 8190 bytes, which is consistent with the 5 kb limit you are observing before encoding. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length).