# multi selection Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selection

How can I handle different files selection ?

**html.erb**

in my form I have several fields and a select box :

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'selected' , pfile.name %> </td>
```

**browser**

http:/myserver/files?x=true&selected=file1&selected=file2

I thought I then could do something like this in my

**controller**

```
if params[:x].present?
  #redirect to my download page with files[] for eg.
  # don't really know how to proceed..
else
  # return _error
end
```

Should I send my selected files(name) as an array ? Bad things may happen if too many files are selected and the URL is too large.. Although the size doesn't really matter , it that kind of situation I reckon it does though :)

Comment: For the length of the request, this is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the multiple option for your check_box_tag, post the form and retrieve the array from your controller.

Here's a good [example](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box#1001-Sending-array-parameters)

You might wanna do something like this :

```
<%=form_tag my_awesome_action_path do |f|%>
  <%@options.each do |option|%>
    <%=f.check_box_tag(:selected, {:multiple => true}, option, nil)%>
  <%end%>
  <%=f.submit_tag "Submit"%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: thanks for the link rb512 ! I'm concerned by the URL length though. Should I not be so ?

Comment: ok cool
by the way I'm affraid the following code doesn't work :
 
<td><%= pfile.check_box_tag(:selected, {:multiple => true}, option,         nil) %> </td>