# How to append a long list of ID's to a URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have an application that has list of ID's as a part of the URL but soon the number of ID's are going to increase drastically. What is the best method to have a big number of ID's in the URL. The ID's can go up to 200 or more at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode your ID array in a string (JSON is an easy format for that) and transmit it as a single variable via POST.

Simple GET Parameters or even the URL itself has some limits on it's length that can no be avoided. Most Webservers also have security Filters in place that wont accept more than a certain number of Parameters. (Suhosin)

See:

- [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)
- [What is apache's maximum url length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length)
- http://www.suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html

Comment: I wish, I have to use the ID's in the URL only as this is a web service as well. And the client is extracting ID's from the URL itself.

Comment: Then you wont be able to send more than a couple of IDs. Maybe split them and call your webservice several times?

Comment: Why not, is there a limitation on the number of characters in the URL, I know IE has 2048 but that is enough for me. I just want to make sure that I am using the best available method to re-write my URL

Comment: Webservers have limitations and also many services like PHP have them. Usually there are additional security filters which further limit the number of parameters.

Comment: Webserver is not a problem as it is private. But what security filters? at what layer are they present.

Comment: A private webserver still has limits. Not all of them can simply removed by configuration. Have you checked PHP.ini configuration and a possible suhosin configuration?

Comment: Ok, I just tried it and it worked perfectly fine with 200 ID's so there is no issue with the number of ID's I am planning to forward. Now the only issue is that how do I write it in the most optimized way. That doesn't look so absurd to the user.

Comment: If it's all numeric ids, just make a comma seperated list?

Comment: Already doing that and somehow it doesn't feel correct. I am sure that I am missing something. There has to be another way a better way to do this.

Comment: Bordering on taste here, but having a one-letter seperator in a list of ids that can not be part of the ids themselfes is probably as short and readable as you can get. (while not packing stuff zip like)

Comment: Probably.. lets see how the search goes.