# $_POST/$_GET Submitted URL too large

Tags: php

I have php scripts to migrate data from one database do another. In one script I call one another to Get the data from the original database, and then it sends it to another. Something like this:

migrateData.php <---> getData.php
and then migrateData.php <---> putData.php

In putData.php im using $_GET, but when its too many Data I get the error saying "The length of the requested URL exceeds the capacity limit of this server". 
I've seen people saying to use $_POST, but i'm not really sure about it.
My migrateData.php:

```
    <?php

  echo "Migration"; 
  $url = "http://localhost/mig/getData.php";
  $client = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $response = curl_exec($client);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo $response; 

  $url = "http://localhost/mig/putData.php?data=".$response;
  $url = str_replace ( ' ', '%20', $url);
  $client = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $response = curl_exec($client);
  echo $response;

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you not just connect to the 2 databases from one script and move the data that way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you send a get request to the server (apache, nginx), it may limit the allowed size of a client's HTTP request-line  (e.g.   ) and the HTTP request header field size.

For example if you have access to the server and its an Apache server you can increase the Apache limits for [limit request line](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) and limit [request field size](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize).

In case of nginx, you can increase the large_client_header_buffers parameter in nginx.conf.

Using POST method will send the fields outside of the client's HTTP request-line, effectively bypassing the server constraint.
Actually POST request are also limited but the default size is bigger.

Using POST or PUT method is recommended instead of changing the server config.

```
<?php
//Your code to get the response here
// ...

$data = ['data' => $response];

// Prepare new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/mig/putData.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Submit the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($ch);

//Output the result
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache's max `$_GET` request length is 8190 bytes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289611/575047) so trying to send heaps of data in a GET request is a bad idea because it might get cut off.

POST is ideal. By default, apache sets post_max_size to 8mb I believe.

To POST, you just need to add these lines I believe to your putData curl

```
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
```