# ERROR http 400 with java and servlets, JSP

Tags: java, servlets

How about community, this error happened to me today and I would like to know if some of you ever happened to you and how to solve it. I am creating an application with servlets in java that the functionality is to have a button, where by clicking it sends me a json with 50 records through the URL so that I can generate an excel. Now, all good when it comes to 10 records, no problem happens, when you have more than 20 records in that json or so, that's where the error happens to me. Investigating I found that the error happens because the header I am sending is too long. Here is an example of what the header I'm sending is:

```
Url: localhost:8080/pruebas/vistas/excel/Reporte_Insertados.jsp?registros=[{"CODPER":"123456","NRO":"1","DNI":"45874587","APELLIDOS_NOMBRES":"ROJAS%20LOPEZ%20GUSTAVO","FECHA":"14/01/2020","MONTO":"150.50","OBSERVACION":"DADSADSA","RAZON_SOCIAL":"","ESTADO":"DATOS%20CORRECTOS","":""}...] so until you have 50 records.
```

So my question is: If any of you solve it or how could I do it from my servlet to allow the header to be long, since it is the problem for which it does not leave me and the error happens to me.
I leave code of my application. Thank you in advance community.

```
My Javascript code:
function exportarReporteInsertados(registrosInsertados){
let tabla_reporte_insertados = $("#tablaCargaMasiva").tableToJSON({});//Here grab all 50 records.
window.location = "excel/Reporte_Insertados.jsp?registros="+JSON.stringify(tabla_reporte_insertados)
}
```

My jsp code to receive the data

```
    <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    String datos = request.getParameter("registros");

    JSONArray jsonArray_datos = new JSONArray(datos);

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=REPORTE_CARGA_MASIVA.xls");

         %>
```

ERROR
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIk6V.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Felipo If you need to send a json, kindly refrain from adding it to the url. The url string has a character limit.Please look at : [What is apache's maximum url length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289585/what-is-apaches-maximum-url-length) . Also, according to convention in order to send a `json` via the request you need to add it to the request body instead of the url. Use an ajax request to send the data to the endpoint instead of passing it via the url.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering try to do that, I passed it by json, but now I have another problem. The functionality was to download an excel made in JSP using those parameters, now it doesn't happen.

Comment: This is my code: $.ajax({
        url: 'excel/Reporte_Insertados.jsp',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType : "json",
        data: {
            registros: tabla_reporte_insertados
        },
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });

Comment: So you are trying to download an excel file in the ui by calling the endpoint with the json in the request body now , but the file is not downloadable ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @FelipeRosado could you please add the related code to the quesstion.

Comment: The functionality is as follows: Click a button, which underneath passes a json and then it reaches a jsp through servlets and this jsp is a design made for excel and therefore should be downloaded for the end user.

Comment: @FelipeRosado you are not receiving the response now ? what is the values in `response` object of the success callback ?